# iPad: presenting a modal view and my parentViewController is now nil?

Tags: ipad, presentmodalviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I have a couple of modal views that have been working "just fine" and now stopped returning to the parent view controller and "the code has not changed."  -- classic problem description.

I debugged the modal view dismissing and the parent view controller is nil, which explains the problem, but not the cause.  I did upgrade my SDK from 4.1.2 to 4.2 so I can start working with iOS 5.  I am suspect of the new memory management ARC and my style of autorelease versus retain/release.

Following is the code from my rootview controller to the AboutViewController:

```
- (IBAction)doInfo:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    AboutViewController *aboutViewController = [[[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    if (aboutViewController) {
        aboutViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        aboutViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        self.navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        [self presentModalViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Following is the dismiss in the AboutViewController back to its parent after pressing a "Done" button.

```
- (IBAction)doDone:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

OK ... I fixed by changing as follows.  Now the question is why did this work before?

```
- (IBAction)doDone:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from [1] about the property `parentViewController`:

*Prior to iOS 5.0, if a view did not have a parent view controller and was being presented modally, the view controller that was presenting it would be returned. This is no longer the case. You can get the presenting view controller using the presentingViewController property.*

So this resolves the issue why this did work before and does not anymore. If building for iOS 5, I would use the `presentingViewController` property, as it is advised by the docs to let the parent view controller (or in this case presenting) dismiss the modal view. However if building for iOS 4 and 5, I would let your code in place as it forwards the call to the appropriate view controller anyway.

If in any case the app ran flawlessly on iOS 5 before recompiling, I would assume that Apple put some runtime-trickery in place that mimics the old behaviour for apps compiled pre-iOS5.

[1] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: FYI - I tested the permutations of target 4.1, 4.2., 4.3 and 5.0 with my code on iPad with iOS4 (except target 5.0), iPad with iOS5 and the Simulator 5.0.  It confirms what you found described in the docs. The iOS 4 code crashes with presentingViewController as "not found."

Answer (score 1):

I have built a category that add `presentingViewController` on iOS 4.

It disables itself on iOS 5.

You can use it seamlessly. Please see [backward-modal](http://github.com/tanin47/backward-modal.git).

I hope this benefits you as much as it does to me; It makes your code more clean!